# Update WMF 4 to WMF 5 via DSC

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm actually playing around with DSC. At the time I've a mixed lab environment where I'm using Powershell 5 (on my laptop) and Powershell 4 on the lab server (WIN 2012 R2). Is there a "simple" solution to update the lab server to WMF 5.x using DSC? I'm actually not sure which DSC resource would be the best to perform this kind of task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to install and import xWindowsUpdate

```
xHotfix WMF5_1
{
  Id = "KB3191564"
  Ensure = "Present"
  Path = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839516"
}
```

The KB Number and Path are for Windows Server 2012 R2, I got them from this [Article](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839516).